# Replace font name of a particular character in text in Power Point

Tags: vba, fonts, symbols, powerpoint

I want to find and replace all instances of the [grave accent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent) `` ` `` with the font named `Rupee Forandian`

Recently the rupee symbol was launched and there is no keyboard symbol for that...

When I try the excel replace function <kbd>CRTL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> with the format function, it changes the font of the entire text string, while I want it to change only the grave accent `` ` ``

I found a solution for Excel, but I need a similar one for Powerpoint 2007.

The VBA used in Excel is:

```
Sub InsertRupeeForandianSymbol()
  Dim X As Long, Cell As Range
  For Each Cell In Selection
    For X = 1 To Len(Cell.Value)
      If Mid(Cell.Value, X, 1) = "`" Then Cell.Characters(X, 1).Font.Name = "Rupee Foradian"
    Next
  Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way to do this I can think of would be

```
 Sub InsertRupeeForandianSymbol()
    Dim oSld As Slide
    Dim oShp As Shape
    Dim x As Long
    Dim y As Long

    For Each oSld In ActivePresentation.Slides
     For Each oShp In oSld.Shapes
         For y = 1 To Len(oShp.TextFrame.TextRange)
          If Mid(oShp.TextFrame.TextRange, y, 1) = "`" Then
            oShp.TextFrame.TextRange.Characters(y).Font.Name = "Rupee Foradian"
          End If
         Next y
     Next oShp
    Next oSld
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In Powerpoint you have to iterate through Shapes to get texts:

```
Sub InsertRupeeForandianSymbol()
    Dim sl As Slide, sh As Shape, X As Long
    For Each sl In ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange
        For Each sh In sl.Shapes
            With sh.TextFrame.TextRange.Characters
                For X = 1 To .Count
                    If .Characters(X, 1).Text = "'" Then .Characters(X, 1).Font.Name = "Rupee Forandian"
                Next
            End With
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

This will change font for all currently selected slides. You may change `ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange` to `ActivePresentation.Slides` and apply to all slides in current presentation.